# Pokemon Go Combat Points over Individual Values

Tags: pokemon-go

I have 2 Dragonites, one with more Combat Points than the other one with more Individual Values. I used pogobag.com to get the values:

[image] **VS** [image]

As you can see, the first one have bigger combat points and the other one have bigger individual values. I want to Power Up and keep only 1. Which would be the ideal one to keep?

PS: Don't mind the green one, it's their current hp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It highly depends on your playstyle, but I tried to generalize as much as possible; Reference is having played many years of Pokémon myself.

Say you want to have the best chances in **lategame**, whereas lategame I refer to when everbody is lvl 30+ and eventually battles between players is implemented, you should go with the one on the *right* (**higher iv**) as until then you should probably have it maxed out in terms of cp.

If you're just happy to have a *strong dragonite* and you **don't care too much about being the best**/ part of the betters, you can go with the one on the **left** as it certainly is also a strong pokemon.

Long terms short: Some people still don't have a *dragonite* so at the moment you're still at a very good position, but in say a month more people will have a dragonite and eventually the *individual values iv* will start to matter more.

Comment: Wow. Nice detailed answer. So will the IV of a pokemon increase when I power it up using candies?

Comment: No! The iv of a Pokemon are randomly distribued values which are defined **once** when the Pokemon is caught. So i.e.: You catch a charmander with 100% iv (perfect values), once you evolve it, it's iv **will stay the same**. **Evolution does not affect iv**. **Neither do candies**, so you if you power up your dragonite on the left it's iv will remain the same (also applies for the one on the right), **only their level and therefore their cp will increase**.

Comment: Okay so I decided to power up the one in the right.