# Should I evolve now or wait for a higher I.V. percentage?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a pretty good grasp on what IV's are and how much they affect your Pokemon. I just need to know for sure. I have these two Squirtles:

1. Squirtle (331 CP 24.4% IV)
2. Squirtle (170 CP 55.6% IV)

Which Squirtle I should evolve? Or should I just wait for a better Squirtle?

Answer (score 2):

The higher the IVs on a Pokemon, the better maximums it can obtain. So if you were to max out the CP bar on both your Squirtles, you'll find that the 55.6% one has better stats overall.

However, 55.6% isn't that great of an IV percentage, as 0x0000eWan has pointed out. If you're concerned with IV's, you'd be best waiting for a Squirtle with a higher percentage, as close to 100% as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely wait for a better one, especially with a Pokémon that costs 125 candy to fully evolve. I'd wait for 80% IV at least.

Another factor that largely impacts Pokémon's combat effectiveness is its moveset. So if you have a low CP Pokémon with high IV perfection rate, you might want to evolve it first to check if you are satisfied with its attack moves and then eventually power up it.

Comment: interesting... evolve first and when you see the moveset, then decide to power up or not... but if you do this, you also waste 100 Dratini candies to evolve it, but I suppose that's how it works

Answer (score 1):

So following [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281396/pokemon-go-combat-points-over-individual-values/281400#281400) post, it depends on what you want.

Additionaly to above link, which mainly consits of the theoretical part and **I highly recommend you to read as you still seem to make up those kinds of decisions**, I'd like to give you an advice on how I handle this.

The best thing to do, in my honest opinion, is to wait. Either you **wait until you have got 125 candies** and evolve then the best out of the contesting *Squirtles*, or if you're lucky enough to find say a **Wartortle** you can evolve it too instead of a Squirtle.

The main aspect in this approach is that evolving as soon as you have 25 candies is mainly pointless (unless you just want the *Wartortle* or highly depend on it as your main pokemon [for winning fights etc.]). Say you evolve at 25 candies, you get a decent Wartortle and just as you're about to farm for more candies you find a better Wartortle.

TL;DR)

i) It depends on your playstyle. Do what you're most confortable with.

ii) I'd suggest to wait until you can fully evolve your Squirtle into Blastoise.